# Using Less Mixins with twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less, mixins, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm making my first attempt to use bootstrap mixins with the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem with bootstrap.  Within the file `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.less` I have the following

```
.form-left{
  .col-md-4;
  .col-md-offset-2;
}
```

So my aim is for the class `form-left` to behave as though it's styled with the bootstrap classes `col-md-4` and `.col-md-offset-2`.

**The problem** is that when I fire up the page, I am confronted with the following error:

> .col-md-offset-2 is undefined
>    (in app/assets/stylesheets/custom.less)

What might I be leaving out?  It's quite possible that it's somehting simple as I'm rather new at this.

Many thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the proper mixins and variables are loaded first:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/mixins.less";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/variables.less";
```

For using columns as mixins, the syntax is different. 
In your specific case, try it like this:

`.make-md-column(4)`
`.make-md-column-offset(2)`

Take a look at here for the full documentation:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less

Comment: Hi Sander, thanks for the reply!  I gave it a shot with `@import "twitter/bootstrap/grid.less";` and was told `.make-md-column(4) is undefined` so I imported according to the [twittter-bootstrap-rails docs:](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#using-stylesheets-with-less) `@import "twitter/bootstrap/variables.less";` and `@import "twitter/bootstrap/mixins.less";` and it worked like a charm.  I've included the modifications in an edit to your answer.  Would never have guessed the syntax difference that you pointed out though.  Many thanks!

Comment: You are right. `twitter/bootstrap/mixins.less` is loading the `grid.less`. Changed my answer to import `twitter/bootstrap/mixins.less`

Comment: I gave it a test and found that I also need `@import "twitter/bootstrap/variables.less";` in order to get past the `undefined` error.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. Updated answer once again. Thanks!